# JavaScript 'this' keyword

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, this

```
var PlaylistView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '#expanded-container',

  initialize: function() {
    this.bg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
    this.$('.list-group').empty();
    var realThis = this;
    _.each(this.bg.Playlist.models, function (song) {
      // append to playlist, rendering song template?
      var songView = new SongView({ model: song });
      console.log(realThis); // THIS is what I want
      console.log(this) // this is NOT what I want
      //this.$el.append(songView.render().el); // hence, this does NOT work
      realThis.$el.append(songView.render().el); // and THIS works
    });
  }
});
```

In the above code, `this` inside `_.each()` function points at the global `window` object because `_.each()` is invoked by the window. However, I still want `this` to point at `PlaylistView`. I have faced many similar situations and I often defined a variable that stored the initial value of this, just like `realThis` variable in the provided example. Is there any other conventional way to deal with this?

**Note:** I am following [this](http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/#what-is-el) book to learn Backbone, and it shows the following code as example.

```
var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
  render: function(){

    // Assume our model exposes the items we will
    // display in our list
    var items = this.model.get('items');

    // Loop through each of our items using the Underscore
    // _.each iterator
    _.each(items, function(item){

      // Create a new instance of the ItemView, passing 
      // it a specific model item
      var itemView = new ItemView({ model: item });
      // The itemView's DOM element is appended after it
      // has been rendered. Here, the 'return this' is helpful
      // as the itemView renders its model. Later, we ask for 
      // its output ("el")
      this.$el.append( itemView.render().el ); // <--- *THIS IS WRONG?
    }, this);
  }
});
```

In this case, wouldn't `this` inside `_.each` loop point at the wrong object, just like in my code? Is this an error in the book or am I misunderstanding something? Thank you!

Reference: [Learning this keyword](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` / context inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback)

Comment: The difference between your two code pieces it that in the second one you pass also `this` as third argument to `_.each`. See the documentation: http://underscorejs.org/#each, *"`_.each(list, iterator, [context])` Iterates over a list of elements, yielding each in turn to an iterator function. The iterator is bound to the context object, if one is passed."* This is also explained in section "Set this of the callback - part 2" in my answer linked to in my previous comment.

Comment: *"In the above code, `this` inside `_.each()` function points at the global `window` object because `_.each()` is invoked by the `window`."* That's actually not correct. `_.each` is executed by the `initialize` method. `this` refers to `window` because `_.each` executes the callback in a way that sets `this` to `window`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change `this` of a particular function by using `.bind()`:

```
function foo() {
    alert(this.x);
}
var boundFoo = foo.bind({x: "bar"});
boundFoo();
```

This alerts "bar".

Saving the outer `this` as `realThis` or `that` is also common if you want access to both the inner and outer `this`.

Underscore uses `.call()` to change `this` of the iterator function you pass it. Specifically, `_.each()` has a third parameter that allows you to specify what you want `this` to be, so that example is correct. See the [underscore.js source](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-15).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. What's the difference between my code and the example code? How come `this` in example code should point at `ListView` while `this` in my code points at `window` ?

Comment: @MaximusS Because of the way underscore works. Underscore changes `this` of your function by using `.call()`. The difference is in the third parameter of `_.each()`. That specifies what the context (a.k.a. `this`) should be.

Comment: I missed the third parameter!

Answer (score 2):

From http://underscorejs.org/#each:

> each `_.each(list, iterator, [context])`
>
> The **iterator** is bound to the **context** object, if one is passed.

Within `initialize()`, `this` points to your Backbone View. If you pass `this` as the 3rd argument to `_.each()` then `this` will refer to your Backbone View within the iterator function.

> I have faced many similar situations and I often defined a variable
>   that stored the initial value of this, just like realThis variable in
>   the provided example. Is there any other conventional way to deal with
>   this?

Yes. If you are in an ES5 (non-IE8) environment, use [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). For backwards compatibility, use [`_.bind()`](http://underscorejs.org/#bind).

```
var func = function (greeting) {
  return greeting + ': ' + this.name;
};

if (usingUnderscore) {
  func = _.bind(func, {name: 'moe'}, 'hi');
} else if (es5environmentHooray) {
  func = func.bind({name: 'moe'}, 'hi');
}

func();
=> 'hi: moe'
```